# Resizing cells according to textView not working?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swift2

I've been having trouble with resizing the cells to the content of a textView. The content of the textView varies depending on how much a user types and posts on the app, so it could be a really long text, or a short one.

As of right now, here's how it looks on the app:
[image: Not showing all text]

however, I've been using this part of code in my viewDidLoad() which has been working fine in my other views of the app:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ProfiletableView.delegate = self
    ProfiletableView.dataSource = self

    self.ProfiletableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.ProfiletableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40.0
}
```

**Note:** That the code above has been working on other tableViews in the app, but in the profile portion where it shows your posts, it displays them like:

[image: It completely hides the textview]

I've been searching back a forth in the code to see if there's anything wrong, comparing to the other classes that are using the resizable code too, and I cannot seem to find anything.

Any ideas what's going on here?

**Edit:** Added Photo of constraints 
[image: Label constraints]

**Edit 2:** Added another photo
[image]

**Edit 3:** Another photo
[image]

Comment: Check the constraints on your cell to make sure there are constraints top to bottom

Comment: How have you set up your constraints for the UITableViewCell? You need to ensure the constraints do not restrict the height of the cell. The challenge here is that a UITextView does not automatically grow in size. If you temporarily try replacing the UITextView with a UILabel (with lines set to 0) does it fix the problem?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes the constraints are there

Comment: @JoGoFo this shows the text, but it gets cut off, like it writes it down like in a sentence, and goes out of the screen, so I cannot tell if it's resizing or not

Comment: Do you mean the text does not wrap, it continues off the screen in one line? If so, you need constraints on the left and right side of the UILabel to prevent it from continuing off the screen

Comment: @JoGoFo I tried that, but the text is still cut off. It doesn't display the whole post

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of your storyboard / XIB file, including the constraints set on the UILabel

Comment: @JoGoFo done! I added the photo

Comment: @JoGoFo I made the constraints bigger, but it still doesn't show the whole text. It cuts off like on the photo I posted with the textView.

Comment: Those constraints don't look right at all. Can you post a pic of the constraints for the UILabel in Size Inspector

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95098/discussion-between-jogofo-and-bruno-recillas).

Comment: make your bottom constraint a greater than or equal one, also make the textView not scrollable.

Comment: @thefredelement yup it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

check by disable textview scrolling.

Comment: A very logical but very very hidden solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive this will solve your problem. But the Ray Wenderlich site has a good article on dynamic sizes within table view cells.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out. @JoGoFo and thefredelement helped me fixed it. It was a matter of constraints and settings for the textView.

Answer (score 0):

I Think Uilabel can do this for you ...
Simply by setting the no. Of lines to zero and word warpping in line breakmode with proper constraints will automatically increase or decrease the hieght of your UITable view cell and label.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code
set textview.isScrollEnabled = false

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

ProfiletableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
ProfiletableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40.0

}

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "abcCell", for: indexPath) as! AbcCell
  cell.textView.delegate = self
   cell.textView.isScrollEnabled = false
 return cell
}
```

Also set below delegate :

```
   func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    ProfiletableView.beginUpdates()
    ProfiletableView.endUpdates()
   }
```